# React/D3: Graph will not display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

In another component I am displaying the contents of data on the screen with no problem. However, I am having problems using that same data to build a graph. When I click submit a graph is to be displayed on the screen but the browser just keep crashing.  Can someone help me figure out what in the code is causing this thanks?

In the console data contains what looks like a JSON file:

```
{data:{action:[action: "changed", timestamp: 12345678], ...}
```

Display Component:

```
class Graph extends Component {

    constructor({nodes}) {
    const times = d3.extent(nodes.action.map(action => {action.action}))
    const range = [50, 450]
    super({nodes})
    this.state = {nodes, times, range}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let group
        const { nodes, times, range } = this.state
        const { target } = this.refs
        const scale = d3.scaleTime().domain(times).range(range)

        d3.select(target)
            .append('svg')
            .attr('height', 200)
            .attr('width', 500)

        group = d3.select(target.children[0])
            .selectAll('g')
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr(
                'transform', 
                (d, i) => 'translate(' + scale(d.timestamp) + ', 0)'
            )

        group.append('circle')
            .attr('cy', 160)
            .attr('r', 5)
            .style('fill', 'blue')

        group.append('text')
            .text(d => d.timestamp + " - " + d.action)
            .style('font-size', 10)
            .attr('y', 115)
            .attr('x', -95)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(-45)')

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Graph name="Timeline"/>

        )
    }

}

export default Graph;
```

Comment: This question needs a better title.

Comment: That's not a JSON (or even javascript), an array cannot contain `key: value` pairs..

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal so what is it then?

Comment: I don't know! try this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(_var_));` (_var_is the 'JSON' variable). Does that work? Maybe it's just wrong because of copypaste from console.

Comment: Chrome developer tools says its JSON.

Comment: After review, it looks like I am getting the data but the processing of the data is where things go wrong.

Comment: Updated constructor now I'm getting action not defined. Can someone tell me if I  am using `map` correctly?

Comment: I am confused because I have never seen that syntax with constructor before. I've always seen `constructor(props)`.